# How can I call two functions in contructor's member initializer list?

Tags: c++, ctor-initializer

Can i call a function in initialize list? please see this code:

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class A {
 public:
  A(string path) : s(cfg.getRoot()) {  // before i call getRoot, i need to call cfg.readFile(path.c_str()), is there any methods? (readFile return void)
  }

  private:
   libconfig::Config cfg;
   const libconfig::Setting & s;  // const &, so initalizer list is the only chance for me to init it
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162021/is-it-ok-to-call-a-function-in-constructor-initializer-list

Comment: @SacrificerXY This is not an exact duplicate; OP needs to know how to call 2 functions once in member initializer list.

Comment: @songyuanyao I see. Perhaps the question's title should be changed to be more specific.

Comment: @SacrificerXY You're right.

Comment: Can't you add regular constructor `libconfig::Config(const string& path)` (or "named" constructor/factory `libconfig::Config libconfig::Config::FromFile(const string& path)`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also make use of the comma operator (although this may or may not be harder to understand for a reader):

```
A(string path) : s((cfg.readFile(path.c_str()), cfg.getRoot())) {}
```

The built-in comma operator evalues from left-to-right and discards the result of the left-hand expression. Note that the double parentheses are necessary. Otherwise it will be parsed as two function arguments to `s`'s constructor.

This will not work correctly if the return type of `cfg.readFile(path.c_str())` has an overloaded comma operator (which is however very rare). In that case you need to cast the result to `void` in order to discard the return value:

```
A(string path) : s((static_cast<void>(cfg.readFile(path.c_str())), cfg.getRoot())) {}
```

---

The lambda approach was already given. You can avoid repeating the return type if you use `decltype(auto)`:

```
A(string path) : s([this]()->decltype(auto){
    cfg.readFile(path.c_str());
    return cfg.getRoot();
}()) {}
```

Again it is a matter of style, whether you prefer giving the return type explicitly or not.

As noted by @songyuanyao in a comment below, if you do not specify a return type or appropriate placeholder, then you will get into trouble if `cfg.getRoot` returns a reference, because the default lambda type is an `auto` placeholder, which will cause contruction of a temporary object from the reference, which you would then bound to `s` and will immediately be destroyed again.

Answer (score 4):

You need to wrap it into a functor, e.g. `static` member function or lambda (since C++11):

```
A(string path) : s([this]() -> const libconfig::Setting & 
                   { cfg.readFile(path.c_str()); return cfg.getRoot(); }
                   () 
                  ) 
{}
```